# Web Scraping by VBA for JavaScript Content Webpage

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to extract a table from [Drainage Services Department](https://www.dsd.gov.hk/EN/Tender_Notices/Current_Tenders/index.html). I have wrote below VBA code, but it does not work. I guess the reason is because this table is JavaScript. Any idea to solve this problem?

```
Sub DSD()
    
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim url As String
    
    url = "https://www.dsd.gov.hk/EN/Tender_Notices/Current_Tenders/index.html"
    
    ie.Visible = False
    ie.navigate url
    
    Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    Set html = ie.document
    
    Dim lists As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim anchorElements As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim ulElement As HTMLUListElement
    Dim liElement As HTMLLIElement
    Dim row As Long

    Set lists = html.getElementsByClassName("ncol-md-12 result")
    row = 1
    
    For Each ulElement In lists
        For Each liElement In ulElement.getElementsByTagName("tbody")
          Set anchorElements = liElement.getElementsByTagName("td")
          If anchorElements.Length > 0 Then
              Cells(row, 1) = anchorElements.Item(0).innerText
               row = row + 1
          End If
    Next liElement
Next ulElement
    
  
    
      
    
ie.Quit
End Sub
```

I am trying to scrape the table from this website.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**
Try this instead. I simply gave it some time to load everything into the lists object that you have set up and that did the trick.

```
 Sub DSD()
    
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim url As String
    
    url = "https://www.dsd.gov.hk/EN/Tender_Notices/Current_Tenders/index.html"
    
    ie.Visible = False
    ie.navigate url
    
    Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    Set html = ie.document
    
    Dim lists As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim anchorElements As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim ulElement As HTMLUListElement
    Dim liElement As HTMLLIElement
    Dim row As Long
    
    'you had put "ncol-md-12 result" it is actually named "col-md-12 result"
    Set lists = html.getElementsByClassName("col-md-12 result")
    row = 1
    
    ''application needs time to load everything into lists.
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    
    ''or with a loop
    ''Do While i < 1000
        ''DoEvents
        ''i = i + 1
    ''Loop
    
    For Each ulElement In lists
        
        For Each liElement In ulElement.getElementsByTagName("tbody")
         
          Set anchorElements = liElement.getElementsByTagName("td")
          If anchorElements.Length > 0 Then
               Debug.Print anchorElements.Item(0).innerText
               Cells(row, 1) = anchorElements.Item(0).innerText
               row = row + 1
          End If
        Next liElement
    Next ulElement
      
ie.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: Oops, thank you for reminding. But even change to correct class name, this code is still not working... :(

Comment: Oh yes you're right. I have updated my code to include some time to let the html objects load into your list. Hopefully that works for what you're doing.